# Gosu: Making image point to cursor

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I'm using [Gosu](http://libgosu.org) on Ruby 1.9.3 MRI

I have a Player class, with it's own x/y variables, aswell as a Cursor class with the same.
Considering the Player and Cursor class don't differ in movement and values are the same, how can I calculate the angle to `#draw_rot` the player in?

[image: screencap of window]
Above: screencap of the game window.

The cursor is an image centered on the actual OS cursor, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle between the two objects is:

```
angle = Gosu.angle(player.x, player.y, cursor.x, cursor.y)
```

which is what you can use as the angle when drawing the player with Image::draw_rot